# Find the closest tile along a path

Tags: math, path, position

I have a tile based game and I need to find the closest tile within a `32px` radius. So say a user is at `400, 200` and the user clicks at `500, 400`. I need to create a path or line from the player to the mouse position on click and the closest tile that is underneath the path within `32px` (or 2 tiles) must be chosen. The map is tiled at `16px`.

A function call to see if a tile is at a given tile position is available `Map.at(x,y)`.

I just don't know the maths to use to work this out.

[image]

The block blocks are within 16px, the red are within 32px. The grey block is the tile to be destroyed and the blue line is the invisible path between the player and mouse.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the closest tile'? What's wrong with the actual tile that the user clicks on?

Comment: The tiles are only 16px by 16px so not easy to target. The closest tile to the player towards the mouse position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work in terms of tile coordinates, the problem becomes a line-drawing problem from the title the user is at to the tile the mouse was clicked in.  A line drawing algorithm would generate, in sequence, all the tiles along a straight-line path between those two tiles.  Just pick the first one where Map.at(x,y) satisfies your requirements and exit the line-drawer.

A number of line drawing algorithms exist.  Two simple ones are [DDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Differential_Analyzer_(graphics_algorithm)) and [Bresenham's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).  Both generate the discrete "pixels" (tiles, in your question) in the correct order.  The DDA is the simple choice if floating point arithmetic can be used in your application.  Bresenham's uses only integer math.

[image: Generated tiles on path]

Comment: Nearly, works. It doesn't seem to work too well with negative gradients.

Answer (score 0):

With a lot of games, it's not necessary a straight line, but a search for the shortest path. If that's where you are heading then you might want to look at [the A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm).

Comment: This is a straight line though. From the player straight to the mouse position on click. I basically just need to find the closest tile, approaching the mouse position.